# If I have a summand $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{0}$ can I replace it with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ if I replace every $n$ by $-n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

For example does $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$ 
Or does $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{\sin^2(n\pi+\frac{1}{2}\pi)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sin^2(-n\pi+\frac{1}{2}\pi)}$$

My guess is that it is true but I have no idea how to go about proving it.

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ Sorry I had not meant to cause confusion over a reordering of the terms. I was using the notation used when encountering summands such as $$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$ and was not trying to infer that I wanted to start the sum at $-\infty$. Thanks!

Comment: If you are summing positive numbers, how could you get a negative sum? How do you start a sum at $n=-\infty$? Such a sum has a meaning only if the series is absolutely convergent (that is, you can reorder terms as you wish), but you should then write $n\in\Bbb Z\backslash \Bbb N$ or some other notation for your set.

Comment: The first is wrong .  First of all, $\frac 1{(-n)^2}=\frac 1{n^2}$. Secondly, the left hand is meant to go up to $-1$, not $1$. The second is problematic, as  the series diverge.

Comment: Fixed the two problems. So I'm guessing this is not a true result then?

Comment: You have to define things carefully.  If you have an absolutely convergent series, then you can rearrange the terms without changing the sum...so you can probably define the left hand in such a way as to make it true.  Without absolute convergence there's not much you can say in general.

Comment: The true result would be $\sum_{n=0}^{-\infty} f(n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(-n)$, and defining correctly the two sums as limits of sequences (the first with decreasing $n$). If your definition involves reordering, you have to assume absolute convergence.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Indeed, the sum does not "start" at $-\infty$. We already use the notation with $-\infty$ at the bottom for Laurent series. And the meaning is precisely what you wrote in your last comment.

I would say that the answer is yes, provided that $\sum_{-\infty}^{-1}a_k$ means $\lim_{n\to -\infty}(a_n+a_{n+1}+\cdots a_{-1})$.

Comment: @bartgol If the definition is clear, then there is of course no problem.

Comment: Would this be true for a complex series?